# ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene 4 was not found. [adobe animate cc 2018]

Tags: adobe

I have similar problem but in Adobe Animate cc 2018 using actionscript 3.0.

This is all the codes I use but nothing works for scene 4:

```
nextbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextClick); 

function nextClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 4"); 
    //nextScene(); 
    //MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 4");
}
```

[image]

[image]